# Gradle Does not download dependency on WorkManager

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, download

When I try to download this library.

```
implementation "androidx.work:work-runtime-ktx:$work_version"
```

It shows me downloading and not downloading. In the end it shows the error of the photo
[image]

Comment: In your other `build.gradle` file, did you include maven classpath? https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/work#declaring_dependencies

Comment: No, Can you help me with the configuration?

Comment: It is described in the redirect link on that page: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies#google-maven , just add `google()` to your classpath dependencies if you didn't have it there.
If you still can't figure out, include code/screenshot of your other `build.gradle` file so I can check if you have the dependencies there.

Comment: I added now, but don't work yet. I forget tell you that I'm using a VPN, because the Google services are blocked for my country. But I don't see any error any location (403), so I think that the vpn works fine

Comment: https://github.com/phamtdat/WorkManagerDependencyDemo I created a demo with work-manager dependencies. It builds on my PC. check both `gradle.build` files for differences, and check in `gradle-wrapper.properties` that you are using gradle version higher than 4.1. If it won't build on your PC, then it may be the issue with VPN.